# Apply XSLT to XML locally without server

Tags: javascript, xml, xslt, xmlhttprequest, client

I have a bunch of XML files and I want to make a local browser for them in html & javascript, where using the buttons `next` and `previous` one can navigate through the results of applying XSLT to XML.

```
[previous]  [next]
 _______________
|               |
|   Result of   |
| applying XSLT | 
|    on XML     |
|               |
 ̅ ̅ ̅ ̅ ̅ ̅ ̅ ̅ ̅ ̅ ̅ ̅ ̅ ̅ ̅
```

I followed the instruction on [XSLT - On the Client @ w3school](https://www.w3schools.com/xml/xsl_client.asp)

It worked for Firefox but fails for Chromium:

```
Cross origin requests are only supported for protocol schemes: http, data, chrome, chrome-extension, https.

xhttp.open("GET", filename, false);
try {xhttp.responseType = "msxml-document"} catch(err) {} // Helping IE11
xhttp.send(""); //**Causes the Error**
```

How can I make this work **cross-browser**?
I want to get html files on-fly rather than generate them and keep with XMLs.

Comment: You would need to make sure you start Chrome explicitly with a command line flag `–allow-file-access-from-files` to be able to have your script load files from the local file system.

Comment: Thanks for your reply. I saw such solutions but actually, I want a cross-browser solution. I edited my question accordingly.

Comment: Not sure what you expect but if Chrome/Chromium only allow such access to the local file system if the special command line flag is used then there is no way with those browsers to achieve this without the flag. That is just a security restriction/policy imposed by the programmers of those browsers. Even newer APIs like `fetch` https://developers.google.com/web/ilt/pwa/working-with-the-fetch-api explain that a local web server is needed in Chrome for local testing.